# Float number not setting it's correct value in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, swift2

I got a switch that takes the name of a city and set it's map coordinates in a global variable:

```
    var lat : CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees.init(0.0)
    var lng : CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees.init(0.0)
        switch city {
    case "malaga":
        lat = 36.719646
        lng = -4.420071
        break
    case "utrecht":
        lat = 52.092876
        lng = 5.104480

        break
    case "rome":
        lat = CLLocationDegrees.init(41.890251)
        lng = CLLocationDegrees.init(12.492373)
    default:
        lat = CLLocationDegrees.init(41.890251)
        lng = CLLocationDegrees.init(12.492373)
        globCountry = "Rome"
    }
    googleLatLng.latitude = lat
    googleLatLng.longitude = lng
```

But since it was sending me to Algeria everytime I was choosing Rome, I did a bit of investigation and seen that rome coordinates weren't correct. After set some breakpoints in the `switch` were the coordinates were set, I seen the map coordinates variables weren't taking their correct value:

[image]

You can see in the console the city variable content is "rome". The breakpoint after set the `lat` float number shows an incorrect value. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by the lat float number?  You are not defining its data type.  If it's not accurate enough, then why don't you just set it as a double number?

Comment: the "lat" float number was refering to "latitude" float number. I've try with double, but is storing the same inacurate value

Comment: The floating point inaccuracy will give you difference in millimeters and should not account for Rome/Algeria distance. What exactly are the coordinates that it gives you for Algeria instead of Rome and where in the code? @Eric D it is not an exact duplicate and should not be closed - the fp error does not explain OP's problem.

Comment: ... And you don't need `break` in Swift `switch` statements...

Comment: @MirekE OP gets 41.890250999999 instead of 41.890251 for their Rome value from the switch. How is that not a duplicate?

Comment: @EricD it does not explain why the coordinates send him to Algeria instead of Rome. The problem is not in the fp error but elsewhere.

Comment: @MirekE `the coordinates send him to Algeria instead of Rome` That's what they say. That's not what I see from their code and screenshot. :)

Comment: let me update please

Comment: @user3033437 Please do. It will help everybody. :) And if I'm wrong, I'll reopen, *of course*. In the meantime, anybody disagreeing with me can vote themselves to reopen the question.